# Find expected red drawn balls when draw $n$ balls?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, combinations

I have $k_1$ red balls and $k_2$ blue balls in a box. Randomly select $n$ balls in the box without replacement. How to find expected number of red (or blue) balls.

This is my solution

The probability to get r red balls from $k_1+k_2$ balls in the box (event X):
$$P_1(X)=\frac{\binom{k_1}{r}\binom{k_2}{n-r}}{\binom{k_1+k_2}{r}}$$

The $r$ can be from $0 $ to $k_1$ balls, so the prob. of the event is
$$P_2(X)=\sum_{r=0}^{k_1}\frac{\binom{k_1}{r}\binom{k_2}{n-r}}{\binom{k_1+k_2}{n}}$$

Finally, we got the expected value as
$$E(X)= \sum_{r=0}^{k_1} r\times \frac{\binom{k_1}{r}\binom{k_2}{n-r}}{\binom{k_1+k_2}{n}}$$

Is it right?

Comment: What do you mean with "in $k$ trails"? It seems to me that $k_1,k_2,n$ are determining and there is no place for an extra parameter $k$.

Comment: $k$ is number of trails and it given. For example, I draw 100 times and count the expected value

Comment: But what is the function of $n$? Aren't you talking about randomly selecting $n=100$ balls here?

Comment: $n$ is number of balls in each drawn times

Comment: Still unclear to me. Can you describe what happens if e.g. $n=2$ and $k=3$?

Comment: Yes. First, I will randomly select $n$ balls in total of $k_1+k_2$ balls in the box. I will count how many red ball in the trail. Then, I throw $n$ ball in the box and repeat the above step again. I repeat with $k$ time and count how many red balls which I drawn

Comment: Then how can it be that in your calculations $k$ does not occur?

Comment: I see.  I did not update the $k$ when I update question. Wait me

Comment: I updated it. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: Never mind. In title there still is a $k$.

Comment: Your endresult is - as Marc remarks in his comment - okay, but can be modified to end up in a simple closed form. Very often (and this is an example) expectations can be found without chasing on the distribution. Your notations $P_i(X)$ are mysterious. As if you are talking about the same event $X$ and two different probabilities on it. In fact your $P_2(X)$ is nothing else but $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me in my question. If I consider the $p_n$ is probability to select $n$ balls, $\sum{p_n}=1$, then I just insert $p_n$ inside of summation term of $E$. Is it right?

Comment: $n$ is not random here (if my understanding is okay). But $R$ - defined as the number of red balls that are drawn - is. Denoting $p_r:=\Pr(R=r)$ we have $\sum_{r=0}^{k_1}p_r=1$ and $\mathbb ER=\sum_{r=0}^{k1} rp_r$. That agrees with what you write in your question, and confirms that your last RHS is a legal expression for $\mathbb ER$.

Comment: Right. It is $r$, not $n$. You are right.

Comment: @drhab: I made a new question that similar above question. Can you help me at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900931/find-expected-number-of-successful-trail-in-n-times ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i=1,\dots,n$ let $R_i$ take value $1$ if trial $i$ results in a red ball, and let it take value $0$ otherwise.

Then $$R:=R_1+\cdots+ R_n$$ stands for the number of red balls.

With linearity of expectation and symmetry we find:$$\mathbb ER=n\mathbb ER_1=\frac{nk_1}{k_1+k_2}$$

---

**edit** for explanation:

As described in your question we will randomly select $n$ of the $k_1+k_2$ balls, but in order to create clarity before doing so we first reserve $n$ spots that are labeled by the numbers $1,2,\dots,n$. The first ball selected is placed on spot $1$, the second on spot $2$, et cetera.

Then event $\{R_i=1\}$ can be recognized as the event that a red ball will be placed on spot $i$.

Essential is here that at the stage of the beginning of the selection **all balls have equal chance to become the one that will be placed on spot** $i$.

There are $k_1+k_2$ balls in total, so that chance must be $\frac{1}{k_1+k_2}$.

Further $k_1$ of the balls are red, so the probability that a red ball will be placed on spot $i$ equals: $$\frac{k_1}{k_1+k_2}$$

If that is not clear enough yet then number the red balls with $1,2,\dots,k_1$ and let $A_j$ denote the event that ball $j$ will be placed on spot $i$.

Then the event that a red ball is placed on spot $i$ is $$A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{k_1}$$ and its probability is: $$P(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{k_1})=\sum_{j=1}^{k_1}P(A_j)=\sum_{j=1}^{k_1}\frac1{k_1+k_2}=\frac{k_1}{k_1+k_2}$$

Comment: Since the R_i are not i.i.d, how does the linearity of expectation apply here? The expected value of, e. g. R_17 is not obvious to me at least.

Comment: 1) linearity of expectation can always be applied.  You don't need i.i.d. for that. 2) Here the $R_i$ are not independent but have equal distribution. I assure you that e.g. balls 1 and 17 have equal chances to be red. This makes it possible to use symmetry in the sense that $R_1$ and $R_{17}$ have the same expectation.

Comment: Agreed on the linearity. Is there an easy way to see why the distributions are equal?

Comment: Compare it with this: blindfolded you grab $n$ balls and then you place them on spots that are labeled with the numbers $1,2,\dots,n$. Can you think of any reason why e.g. the probability that spot $4$ receives a red ball will be different than the probability that spot $12$ receives a red ball?...I am telling you there is none! This situation does not essentially differ from picking out balls one by one saying: "you are the first, you are the second.." et cetera.

Comment: That is pretty slick. Do you know if there is a way to translate that into a rigorous argument? The assertion essentially seems to be that there is a symmetry in the problem.

Comment: I have edited something to make things more clear.

Answer (score 2):

The probability to draw $\ell$ red balls out of $r$ total draws is
$$
\frac{\binom{k_1}{\ell}\binom{k_2}{r-\ell}}{\binom{k_1+k_2}{r}}.
$$
This follows a [hypergeometric distibution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution), and thus has expectation 
$$
r\frac{k_1}{k_1+k_2}.
$$
Note that, similarly, the expected value of drawn blue balls equals
$$
r\frac{k_2}{k_1+k_2}
$$
and thus that the sum equals $r$.

Comment: I have updated my equation. Your equation is look like me. Could you check it again. I think it must be summation

Comment: Your formula for the expectation in the form of a sum is indeed correct. A closed form for this sum is the fraction I gave in the answer.